# Access to stream from TV usb Tuner with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture, television, tuner

Is there any way to open video stream from tv tuner connected by usb? It is simple DVB-T tuner.

I tried with VideoCapture but it didn't work (it works for me only with webcam).

Ofc i know there many applications to open stream from tv tuner like VLC etc. but the thing is i
need it for my application processing tv image with OpenCV (written in C++). 
In other words, i need in my application frames grabbed directly from the device.

Comment: had the same problem, VideoCapture would only read the stream on a linux box, but not from xp. ended up abusing libvlc to build a 'mock' VideoCapture

Answer (score 0):

You might check out http://www.mythtv.org MythTV is an open source DVR with a lot of public contributors. You may be able to check out how they accomplished your goals in their program. Best of luck!